# Powershell - Find and optionally delete a user in the Local Administrators Group on multiple Servers

Tags: powershell

I have the following code to find all users that are members of the Server Local Administrators Group from a given list of Servers. Can someone advise the best way to modify this so that I can search for just one specific username within the list of Servers?

Further to this, could someone add a bit of optional code to delete the named user from the Local Administrators Group if they are found to be in it?

We are looking for ways to clear out the Group after the projects have finished building and configuring production Servers, before those servers go live.

```
$SERVERS = GC .\HOST.TXT

FOREACH ($C in $Servers) {
WRITE-HOST $c
[string]$strComputer = $c 
$computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer") 
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find("Administrators")
$members= $Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)} 

foreach($user in $members) 
{ 
$objUser = [ADSI]("WinNT://$strComputer/$user")
[string]$output = $strComputer + "," + $user + "," + $objUser.SchemaClassName + "," + $ObjUser.Description
write-host $output
$output |out-file -append .\L_out.txt
Remove-Variable objUser
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement searching for the string you desire and then put some user input on it to delete if the user enters 'Yes'

```
if ($user -eq "****INSERT USER NAME HERE****") {
    if (Read-Host -Prompt "Delete user? (Yes/No)" -like "yes") {
        Remove-ADUser -Identity $user -Server $C            
    }
}
```

This should be in your `foreach($user in $members) {` block

Comment: more simplistic might be to try:

$name = read-host "user?";

$members= $Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)} | ?{$_ -like $name} | remove-aduser